# Python Scraper - Request Post Function Not Returning Correct Page

Tags: html, python-3.x, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I am working on my first website scraper and have ran into another issue. Below is my code.  The website that is returned is the main page not the specific site for the parcel number I searched.

Am I using the wrong html class to identify the search function?  Or is there something missing in the Python code?  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
web_page = 'https://mcassessor.maricopa.gov/index.php'
web_header ={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {'homeSearchField' : '10218779'}
response = requests.post(web_page, data=payload, headers=web_header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print (soup.prettify())
```

Comment: try `requests.get('https://mcassessor.maricopa.gov/mcs.php?q=10218779', headers=web_header)`

Comment: Thanks.  That would work great.  But what if I want to change the number at the end, the 10218779.  Is that a way put it into the search bar and then get the website?

Comment: Use the `params` argument. Example: `payload = {'q':'10218779'}; url = 'https://mcassessor.maricopa.gov/mcs.php'; r = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=web_header)`